# Autofac: add new types to container based on already registered items

Tags: c#, autofac

Situation: We have several classes, which are registred as interface. Also this classes are marked with custom attribute. We want to go throught all registered components in the end of App containew building and create new registrations based on ot. For example,

```
[CustomAttribute]
public class Foo: IFoo
{
    [NewCustomActionAttribute("Show me your power!")]
    public void Do() {}
}
```

So we are doing this - `builder.Register<Foo>.As<IFoo>();`
And a lot of the similar classes into another plugins. After all plugins beeing registered, we want to add new class to builder, e.g. ICustomAction with some metadata like caption and module, and load it later based on this registration. 
What is the best way to do that?

UPDATE:

```
var types = // get all registered types
foreach (var typeToProceed in types.Where(_ => _.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault != null)
{
   var customMethodAttributes = // Get NewCustomActionAttributes from this type
   for each customAttr
       builder.Register(new CustomClass(customAttr.Caption, dynamic delegate to associated method);
   end for aech
}
```

I do not want to do it in the vase bootstrap, because there may be a lot of another attributes. The best way is to add (only once) new classes when this item (Toolbar) is requsted first.

Comment: Where are `caption` and `module` in your sample code?

Comment: caption is the "Show me your power!", module is the name of module where this Foo class is defined. We wanna look through all public methods with NewCustomActionAttribute assigned and add new registrations.

Comment: Please show the registration you want to have for your sample code in Pseudocode.

Comment: Is it correct, that your problem is the fact that there is no way to get the registered classes from a `builder`?

Comment: My problem that I do know the best way to do this search via modules :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. Is there a reason why you don't perform that special registration when you perform the registration for the class itself?

Comment: Understand your question... I do not want to rgister Foo as CustomAttribute<Meta>, because I do not need it actually - I need to register new CustomClass instances based on public methods from Foo class.

Comment: What I meant was: Why don't you change `builder.Register<Foo>.As<IFoo>();` to this: `builder.Register<Foo>.As<IFoo>(); builder.RegisterCustomClasses<Foo>()`? `RegisterCustomClasses` would be implemented similar to the body of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new extension method `RegisterCustomClasses` that handles the registration:

```
public static class AutofacExtensions
{
    public void RegisterCustomClasses<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods();
        var attributes = methods.Select(x => new
                                        {
                                            Method = x,
                                            Attribute = GetAttribute(x)
                                        })
                                .Where(x => x.Attribute != null);

        foreach(var data in attributeData)
            builder.RegisterInstance(new CustomClass(data.Attribute.Caption, 
                                                     data.Method));
    }

    private static NewCustomActionAttribute GetAttribute(MethodInfo method)
    {
        return method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NewCustomActionAttribute))
                     .OfType<NewCustomActionAttribute>()
                     .FirstOrDefault()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
builder.Register<Foo>.As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterCustomClasses<Foo>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This approach is even better then I was thinkin of.